# Can we create a table in MySQL from scratch using INTO without defining using CREATE before?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL construct:

What I tried todo is to extract data from `RBP` table and
straight-away creating it into a `new_table`

```
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT pdb_id, chain_id FROM RBP
        WHERE exp = "X-ray" AND 
       header = "RNA BINDING PROTEIN/RNA"
```

But what I got is this:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'MYDB.new_table' doesn't exist")
```

Is it possible to do that without performing this before?

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
        pdb_id char(8)
        chain_id char(2)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a virtual table (view) from the existed table as follows:

CREATE VIEW view_name as SELECT  column_name from table_name where ;

In your case, you can write

CREATE VIEW view_name as SELECT pdb_id, chain_id from RBP
WHERE exp = "X-ray" AND header = "RNA BINDING PROTEIN/RNA";

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not create tables when using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT *` syntax but you can use `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT ...` as described in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

Comment: Thanks, I've changed my reply